# Is there a functional way to set a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am looking for something like this:

```
set("variablename", "value");
```

Why I need this? I want to write the following without creating a new function:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, success, fail);
var success = function(stream) {
   var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
}
```

Comment: var variablename = "value";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I am assume the context is window which is global context

```
function set(variablename,value){
   window[variablename] = value;
}
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: pass variablename as String